# Javascript: how to extract words from index1 to index2?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text and I need to extract words from index1 to index2.

`"This is a text from where a part should be extracted"`

index1 = 3, index2 = 7

`result = "text from where a "`

How to do this with regExp, considering that words may be separated with multiple spaces?

Comment: Why regex? No need for regex...

Comment: So you mean just split and join? How to preserve right number of spaces between words?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR do you know the starting and ending index number of your words that you want to extract...?? means will it always be from 3rd word to the 7th word and same length...??

Comment: Do the extra whitespaces count as "one" space in your mind so `...  text from  [tons of white spaces here]        where part ...` would result in the same thing?

Comment: check this link of [`substr`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) method... do you need this one...??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you a hint.

```
"This is a text from where a part should be extracted"
    .match(/[^\s]+\s*/g)
    .slice(3, 7)
    .join('');
```

You should be able to make that into a generic function easily enough.

Cheers

Comment: It will fail with the "multiple spaces" requirement. I think mutliple spaces count as one space between words, but you have to keep them.

Comment: After your edit: Your join now drops those extra whites spaces.

Comment: @epascarello, yeah, was in the process of cleaning up. Didn't see the multiple spaces requirement. Updated again, now should work. Let me know if it needs another touch up. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"This is a text from  where a part should be extracted"
.split(/\s+/).slice(4,8).join(" ");
```

This version removes the extra white spaces.